# MPEG-TS pointer_field max value

Tags: mpeg2-ts

What is the max value for the Pointer_filed  (ISO/IEC 13818-1  2.4.4.1) in MPEG 2 standart?
I write my own library on C# for parsing ts files and found this:

[image]

As we can see here pointer_field for this table is 0xb5 bytes. EIT table header begin with 0x4E 0xF2 but end in another table and i can't get EIT section length for this table.

ps I get this EIT stream from Eutelsat 36B satellite.

Answer (score 1):

It is an 8-bit field, so the max value would be 255.

Reading ISO/IEC 13818-1 2.4.4.1:

> pointer_field – This is an 8-bit field whose value shall be the number
> of bytes, immediately following the pointer_field until the first byte
> of the first section that is present in the payload of the Transport
> Stream packet (so a value of 0x00 in the pointer_field indicates that
> the section starts immediately after the pointer_field). When at least
> one section begins in a given Transport Stream packet, then the
> payload_unit_start_indicator (refer to 2.4.3.2) shall be set to 1 and
> the first byte of the payload of that Transport Stream packet shall
> contain the pointer. When no section begins in a given Transport
> Stream packet, then the payload_unit_start_indicator shall be set to 0
> and no pointer shall be sent in the payload of that packet.

The rest of your EIT table is contained in the following packet.